# How to force tar to include certain directories when using --exclude option

Tags: tar

I need to backup a hierarchy.  I need to keep the image as small and fast as possible.  I use

```
tar -c --exclude="..."
```

with several `--exclude=".."` patterns to omit quite a few directory/file patterns, and that works fine.

However, the hierarchy has several `.git` sub-directories dotted around inside it and I do want to *include* anything below such directories encountered in the backup.  There is a chance directories/files below `.git` *might* match the `--exclude="..."` patterns, and they would currently get excluded.

Is there any way to tell `tar` that *anything* below a `.git` is to be *included*, regardless of `--exclude`?  Or how could I handle this requirement?